# Register first user with specific role in ASP.NET Core (how to modify AccountController actions)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm migrating an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app to ASP.NET Core (with .NET 5). I want to set the role of a user if he or she is the first registered user (when database is empty of data). I'm using Identity to user authentication )with `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` class, adding new properties).

In the previous version I modified AccountController file:

- `Register` action was removed (only the owner/admin of the web could register new users).
- I added a new action `SetFirstAdmin`, similar to removed `Register` adding Admin role to the registered user (adding first name and last name as registry fields).
- In `Login` action, first I checked if there is a user with Admin role. If there is no Admin the user was redirected to `SetFirstAdmin` action.

I noticed that `AccountController` is missing ASP.NET Core projects (since ASP.NET Core 2.1 I think), so I don't know how to disable register, change Login action and add new action to `AccountCotroller`. Is it posible? Or is there another way to set a role to the first user?

Comment: Asp.net core Identity using [Scaffold Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to add and view the generated files to review the template interaction with Identity: Right-click on the project > Add > New Scaffolded Item. From the left pane of the Add New Scaffolded Item dialog, select Identity > Add. In the Add Identity dialog, select the Identity page you want. After that, you could find the relates page from the Areas> Identity >Pages >Account folder. Then, in the register page, you can set roles.

Comment: Thank you @ZhiLv , when I select Account\Login and Account\Register I get this error: There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyProjectName'.'